# Property [cliente] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

Tengo el siguiente error, llegaron a punto de decirme que era porque estaba usando español y no ingles y no creo que ese sea el problema, tengo una tabla turnos(id,cliente,profesional etc) y una tabla personas (id, nombre,apellido etc) y quiero acceder a los datos de la persona de la fk sin necesidad de hacer dos consultas por id. Les adjunto los modelos y las estructuras de las tablas y el error. Gracias espero puedan ayudarme.

***Modelo Turno***

```
public function cliente() {
  return $this->hasOne(App\Persona::class,'cliente');
}
```

***Modelo de Persona***

```
public function turno(){
  return $this->belongsTo(App\Turno::class);
}
```

Me tira error en la siguiente linea de código, en la cual quiero acceder al campo nombre de la persona de la fk asociada al turno recuperado. Me gustaría saber porque no funciona ya me gustaría no hacerlo con un solo registro sino con una coleccion.

```
public function showPaciente($id) {
$aux = \App\Turno::find($id);

dd($aux->cliente->nombre); /*Property [cliente] does not exist on this collection instance.*/
```

Aclaro quiero una relacion 1 a 1 ya que una persona puede tener solo un turno y un turno puede ser ocupado por solo una persona.

Comment: Es ese que subí, solo que le puse el nombre Rol en lugar de Turno, ya lo corregí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Empecemos por que parece que tienes las relaciones mal aplicadas, ya que:

- Una persona tiene asignado un turno

Entonces

- Un turno pertenece a una persona

Dado lo cual tus modelos deben quedar así:

Modelo Persona

```
class Persona extends Model 
{

    public function turno()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Turno::class);
    }
}
```

Modelo Turno

```
class Turno extends Model 
{

    public function persona()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Persona::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora a nivel de la consulta:

- Obtienes el id del turno primero
- Accedes posterior a la relación de turnos con personas por medio del método `persona` y finalmente a la propiedad deseada `nombre`

Código

```
$turnoId = Turno::findOrFail($id);

$turnoId->persona->nombre;
```

Para cuando se te presente que una relación genere un valor `null` y entonces decirte que:

> "Trying to get property of non-object"

Dispones de acciones tales como:

- Hacer uso del helper [optional](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-optional)
- Al momento de obtener el `id` por el cual filtrarás al inicio puedes ocupar el método `findOrFail()` para que desde el inicio si ese valor por el cual planeas encontrar no existe retorne una excepción
- Bien puedes hacer uso de `??` que te dará la posibilidad de retornar un alerta si no existe, de esta forma: `$foo->bar->algo ?? "entonces otro"`

**REFERENCIAS**

- [Relaciones (one to one) en Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one)

Comment: Hice lo que me comentaste y me dice el error "Trying to get property of non-object"